# Java Timer.cancel() not cancelling timer

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I have a simple socket server and client set up in Java. I want to implement a method that checks for a connection timeout. Basically, the client sends `01101011 01100101 01100101 01110000` to the server every 5 seconds. The server then checks if it already has a connection established with the client it's received the string from.

If it doesn't, then it adds the client's IP to an array called `connections`, and starts a 30 second timer. If the 30 second timer reaches the end, it will remove the client from the `connections` array.

Otherwise, if it does already have a connection established with the client, then it cancels the 30 second timer and restarts it.

This is my code:

```java
//This if statement fires every 5 seconds when it received the string from the client
if(o.equals("01101011 01100101 01100101 01110000")) {
    Timer timeoutTimer = new Timer();

    if(Arrays.asList(connections).contains(connection.getOtherEnd().getAddress())) {
        timeoutTimer.cancel();
        timeoutTimer.purge();
        timeoutTimer = new Timer();
    }
    else {
        connections = ArrayModification.append(connections, connection.getOtherEnd().getAddress());
        System.out.println("Client connected");
    }
    timeoutTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            connections = ArrayModification.remove(connections, connection.getOtherEnd().getAddress());
            System.out.println("Client disconnected");
        }
    }, 30000);
}
```

It works fine for about 30 seconds, but then, it for some reason executes the timer tasks that should've been cancelled.

Here's my output:

```
Client connected <- Happens when the client first connects
Client disconnected <- Happens 30 seconds later from the timer task that should've been cancelled
Client connected
Client disconnected
Client connected
Client disconnected
Client connected
```

I could not figure out why the cancelled timers are still running. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Each time the `if` statement runs, you create a new `Timer` so your canceling the new instance you just created and not the one that might have been created earlier

Comment: @MadProgrammer it is actually the other way around: the "old" timer is cancelled, the "new" timer is not.

Comment: On a sidenote: the code can be simplified by moving timer creation and -start into the `else` branch, and dthen eliminating the `if`-branch by negating the condition.

Comment: @Turing85 `Timer timeoutTimer = new Timer();` shadows anything else which might be declared globally, so when they call `timeoutTimer.cancel`, they are cancelling the NEW instance, not any that were previously created.  They then create ANOTHER instance (so that's now two).  I also don't see anywhere that they create store this reference to be used later.  So right now, they are not cancelling the timer that was "previously" created, as they have NO reference to it - so it's just a mess

Answer (score 4):

So, you

- Create a new instance of `Timer`
- If the `if` condition is `true`, you cancel that instance and create another one
- Then you schedule the task, but you maintain no reference to the instance which was created, so there's no way to reference it again to cancel it...?

[image]

So, at the end of the method, you ALWAYS create and schedule ANOTHER `Timer`, to which you have no reference to cancel in the future.

The problem is, I think what you want is a `Timer` per connection.  This would suggest that you might want to associate the timer with the connection object itself, but the code you've supplied is out of context so it makes it difficult to ascertain directly what might be a suitable solution

Comment: Thanks! This helped me solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you override `timeoutTimer` with another instance of `Timer`. So you don't call `cancel()` on your initial `Timer` you scheduled the `TimerTask`, you call it on a newly created timer.

Comment: It is actually the other way around: the "old" timer is cancelled, the "new" timer is not.

Comment: Since first statement is `Timer timeoutTimer = new Timer();` I don't see how the first timer should be canceled anyhow with that snipped you posted. How you know it's "old"/"new" timer?

Comment: the "old" timer is the one created in the outer `if`-branch. The "new" timer is the one created in the inner `if`-branch.

Comment: Yeah but you override the unconditionally created time before it can get canceled.

Comment: The outer timer gets cancelled (and would as per the API) reject future requests. The local variables is then, however, assigned a new `Timer` that is not cancelled, hence the future submission will be executed.

Comment: How you're supposed to cancel the `Timer` anyway when it's a local variable living only for one "ping".

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it. With the help of commenters, I figured out that I was creating a new Timer every time, and not cancelling the old one. Here is how I fixed it.

I first created an object called Timeout. Here's what it looks like:

```java
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Timeout {
    String address;
    Timer timer;
    TimerTask timerTask;

    protected Timeout(String address) {
        this.address = address;
        this.timer = new Timer();
    }

    public void setTimerTask(TimerTask timerTask) {
        this.timerTask = timerTask;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void startTimer() {
        timer.cancel();
        timer.purge();
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 30000);
    }
}
```

I then changed the code in the server to this:

```java
if(o.equals("01101011 01100101 01100101 01110000")) {
    boolean contains = false;
    for (Timeout timeout : connections) {
        if (timeout.getAddress().equals(connection.getOtherEnd().getAddress())) {
            contains = true;
            timeout.setTimerTask(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    connections = ArrayModification.remove(connections, timeout);
                    System.out.println("Client disconnected");
                }
            });
            timeout.startTimer();
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!contains) {
        Timeout timeout = new Timeout(connection.getOtherEnd().getAddress());
        timeout.setTimerTask(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                connections = ArrayModification.remove(connections, timeout);
                System.out.println("Client disconnected");
            }
        });
        connections = ArrayModification.append(connections, timeout);
        System.out.println("Client connected");
    }
}
```

With this new setup, everything works as it should!